# ios-how to store multidimensional arrays into the NSUserDefaults

Tags: ios, arrays, nsuserdefaults

As i said in the title.

I create an array like this:

```
array array array array array

array array array array array

array array array array array

array array array array array
```

this is same as the chess board.

And then i store it:

```
 [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults]setObject:ary forKey:@"game"];
```

And then i put it from NSUserDefaults .

I can get the array.
but if i modify the array, and store it again. It's not working now.

Comment: Use of `NSMutableArray` is required, fetch it, modify it, create a new one, save it.

Comment: Not working how? What is in the arrays?

Comment: @Wain same as the chess board.  each cell is a array with the number of int.

Comment: Have you written this line after modifying it. `[[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] synchronize];`

Answer (score 0):

```
SMutableArray *mutableArray0 = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
NSMutableArray *mutableArray1 = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
NSMutableArray *mutableArray2 = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];

multiArray = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
multiArray = [NSMutableArray arrayWithObjects:mutableArray0, mutableArray1, mutableArray2, nil];

NSMutableArray *mutableArray0 = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
[mutableArray0 addObject:[NSNumber numberWithInt:myNumber]];
NSUserDefaults *defaults = [NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults];
[defaults setObject:mutableArray0 forKey:@"myMutableArray"];
[[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] synchronize];    
NSMutableArray *mutableArray0 = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
[mutableArray0 addObject:[NSNumber numberWithInt:myNumber]];

NSMutableArray *multiArray = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
[multiArray addObject:mutableArray0]; 
NSUserDefaults *defaults = [NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults];
[defaults setObject:multiArray forKey:@"myMutableArray"];
[[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] synchronize];
```

You can try like this.Hope will work for you :)